# How to hide a namespace for specific user on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding, k8s-cluster-role

I have three namespaces

- prod
- dev
- stage

And I have two users

- prod-user : have full access for "prod" namespaces but have no access for "dev" and "stage"
- dev-user : have full access for "dev" and "stage" namespaces but don't have access on "prod"

On "prod-user", if I get namespace "kubectl get ns", I want that it's show only "prod" namespace

On "dev-user", if I get namespace "kubectl get ns", I want that it's show only "dev" and "stage" namespaces,

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Role & RoleBinding  to restrict users to specific to allow CRUD operations for a particular namespace. [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did it, but i want that user "prod-user" don't see "dev" and "stage" namespces when if he do "kubectl  get ns".

Comment: I'll need to see your role and rolbindings. Also, which user is logged in when you run kubectl commands?